# CSOM Search for documents

Tags: csom, search-results, sharepoint-search

I am using search API to search keyword for documents (pdf, word) but the result returned contains only the document Title and path...etc

**I want to return the Paragraph which contains the search keyword and Line number and Page number**.

How?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I do not think the search can return information about page numbers and line numbers of where the search string was found in the document

Comment: Actually, I don't know if it can but I think it's very important for the client to know these information (at least for me) in order to ignore irrelevant documents.